# grpc-java CallCredentials without thisUsesUnstableApi?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I've got a gRPC server acting as a proxy. It forwards a few auth-related headers in a `ServerInterceptor`/`ClientInterceptor` pair. See below for most of the code.

My question is: the only way I've seen so far to set `Metadata` headers for outgoing gRPC calls is to make a subclass of `CallCredentials`. To do that, though, you need to confess your sins by implementing the `thisUsesUnstableApi` method.

### Is there any stable alternative to making a subclass of `CallCredentials`?

---

The `ServerInterceptor` grabs the relevant headers out of `Metadata` and stuffs them in the `Context`:

```
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata requestHeaders,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    Context contextWithAuth = Context.current();
    // Cutting out my utility classes that won't help those looking for an example.
    for (...) {
      contextWithAuth = contextWithAuth.withValue(Context.key(foo), requestHeaders.get(Metadata.Key.of(...)));
    }
    return Contexts.interceptCall(contextWithAuth, call, requestHeaders, next);
  }
```

The `ClientInterceptor` grabs the headers out of the `Context` and stuffs them in the outgoing `Metadata`:

```
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
      MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
    return next.newCall(
        method,
        callOptions.withCallCredentials(
            new CallCredentials() {
              @Override
              public void applyRequestMetadata(
                  RequestInfo requestInfo, Executor appExecutor, MetadataApplier applier) {
                try {
                  Metadata headers = new Metadata();
                  for (...) {
                    headers.put(Metadata.Key.of(...), Context.key(...).get());
                  }
                  applier.apply(headers);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                  applier.fail(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withCause(e));
                }
              }

              @Override
              public void thisUsesUnstableApi() {
              }
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most header processing is handled with `ClientInterceptors` (and `ServerInterceptors`). For example, to add a header to a client:

```java
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
      MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
    return new new SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
      @Override
      public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
        headers.put(MY_HEADER_KEY, "someValue");
        super.start(responseListener, headers);
      }
    }
  }
```

`CallCredentials` is less powerful and more powerful than `ClientInterceptors`. It can only add request headers, but it is easy to make asynchronous and it has access to precise connection information (security, remote ip, etc). Easy asynchronous is very helpful when needing do I/O to obtain an OAuth token and being able to access security information of the transport is helpful to ensure that it is safe to transmit the bearer token. It is also called just before sending the RPC so the token can be very fresh. This doesn't sound all that relevant for you.

If you are wanting to use `CallCredentials` and just bothered by the unstable API then you can encourage it to be stabilized on its [experimental-tracking issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1914). It is an older API and hasn't changed much, so may be close to stabilization.

(Aside: the annoying `thisUsesUnstableApi()` method is because the *name* `CallCredentials` is stable, so users can pass them around safely, but implementing it and calling it is unstable. That is a rare situation so the method is there to warn you.)

If you are making a proxy, it may be easier to use `ClientCall` and `ServerCall` directly, without the stubs. That carries the cost of needing to manage flow control directly (e.g., calling `request()`), but overall might be a better fit. You also may be interested in my fully-generic [proxy example](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/blob/grpc-proxy/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/grpcproxy/GrpcProxy.java).